# Noncomformant arguments error although using element-wise operations

Tags: octave

I am using element-wise operation and am still getting the error nonconformant arguments in Octave. The code has been given below

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
g = zeros(size(z));
% Instructions: Compute the sigmoid of each value of z (z can be a 
% matrix,vector or scalar).

g = 1./(1+exp(-z));
end
```

The error is 
"error: sigmoid: operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x4)"

Could someone please help? Thanks

Comment: Runs fine on my Octave 5.1.0 on Windows 10. Which version do you use? What is your test input?

Comment: @HansHirse I am using version 4.2.2 . The function is working properly when I am using scalars but it's giving the above mentioned error when I input any vector or matrix

Comment: Probably there are multiple definitions of the sigmoid function in your octave path. You need to set the current path to the directory that contains the correct function file.

Comment: You are probably accidentally running a version of your function which used `/` instead of `./` . Also, note that the `zeros` line in your function does nothing since you overwrite `g` in the next step. you probably meant to say `g(:)` or something along those lines if what you meant to do was preallocation.